# React search and filter: TypeError: setFilterFn is not a function

Tags: reactjs, search, filter

I'm working on a search and filter function. When I type text into the search box, the content that matches the criteria will be filtered out. I want to use the following function to achieve this, but when I type, the **"TypeError: setFilterFn is not a function"** will occur.
I don't know where goes wrong, How should I fix it?
Thx a lot!

```
  const [setFilterFn] = useState({ fn: items => { return items; } })

  const handleSearch = e => {
    let target = e.target;
    setFilterFn({
        fn: items => {
            if (target.value != "")
                return items;
            else
                return items.filter(item => item.fullName.toLowerCase().includes(target.value.toLowerCase()))
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: const [filterFn, setFilterFn] = ...

Answer (score 1):

The quick fix... add a comma ...

```
const [,setFilterFn] = useState((items) => ( items));
```

it also looks as if you may have an issue with your logic..

```
if (target.value != "")
```

The operator here should probably be `===` otherwise you will only filter for blank strings.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at useState function, that function returning array with two arguments, first value of state , the second is callback function which will change your satate value. You are providing only one value, so react assuming that is value not a function. You can read more in [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usestate)